# lvalue required as left operand

Tags: c, embedded

I have

```
LCD_DATAPORT = (LCD_DATAPORT & 0x0F) | (Command & 0xF0)
```

I want to send 4_bits of my data to the upper bits of the data port. 
Where `LCD_DATAPORT` is defined as `PORTA` which is defined as `0`. However it keeps giving me

> lvalue required as left operand error.

What can I do?

Comment: You mean ... `0 = <some calculation>;`?

Comment: no, 0 is representing a port number in a microprocessor

Comment: Oh! Ok, out of my league.

Comment: Please post the *actual definitions*. Presumably you are using some supplied library code for the microprocessor.

Comment: I'm with @pmg. You are probably trying to assign something to a port number definition (that is an integer constant) instead of a variable mapped on your port register of your micro (something like LCD_DATAPORT_REG).

Comment: Without knowing the target, it is not possible to assist, but obviously you cannot assign a literal `0`.  Normally a port macro might be defined `#define PORTA ((uint8_t)(*PORTA_ADDR))` where `PORTA_ADDR` in turn might be defined for example: `#define PORTA_ADDR ((volatile uint8_t*)(0x4000))`.  PORTA being defined as `0` is not very plausible.  Where is it defined, and by whom (you or the chip vendor for example)?  You are either not using it as intended, or it is not correctly defined.

Comment: You need to write your data to the Port A's data register, . As Clifford said, you cannot write it to 0. That is nonsense. Find the Port A data register define in the MCU's header file, and put that on the left side. Maybe start with some LED examples to to learn how to write to the pins.